# List all branches in all git subproject of repo project

Tags: git, repo

I have a huge repo project with many git subprojects. *(It is AOSP)*
I want to find specific branches everywhere in the repo project.
Is there already a command to list all (or matched) branches in all git subprojects or does it need some scripting?
Do git submodules support such a command?

Example of expected output:

```
sub/project1:main
sub/project1:v1
sub/project2:main
sub/project2:v1
...
```

Comment: Did you try git fetch --all?

Comment: bear with me, what is AOSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
repo forall -p -c git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/*
```

Nice feature of "repo forall -p" that it prints subproject path only if a subcommand has an output. Hence paths without branches, which is common for repo, are not printed. Only paths with local branches are printed!

"git for-each-ref ..." prints raw list of branches

Answer (score 2):

There is the `foreach` command for git submodules. See the [submodule documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

You could list all branches with `git submodule foreach 'git branch'` to get a list of all local branches of every submodule.